# SQL Query to evaluate multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to retrieve only the customers from an order table who have paid for all the orders. (Paid = 'Y').

The order table looks like this:

```
Cus #     Order #    Paid 
111            1        Y 
111            2        Y
222            3        Y
222            4        N
333            5        N
```

In this example the query should only return customer 111.

The query

```
Select * from order where Paid = 'Y';
```

returns customers that have paid and unpaid orders (ex. customer 222) in addition to customers who have paid for all of their orders (customer 111).

How do I structure the query to evaluate all the orders for a customer and only return information for a customer that has paid for all the orders?

Comment: Are there more than three possible values for the paid column? If not, you should be using a boolean data type, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Looking the problem a different way, you need only the customers who don't have any unpaid order.

```
sel cus from order group by Cus having min(Paid) = 'Y';
```

The above query also utilizes the fact that 'Y' > 'N'.

SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6022/1

If you need to select all different orders for eligible customers, you may use OLAP functions:

```
select cus,order,paid from (select cus,order,paid,min(paid) 
                over (partition by cus)minz from order)dt where minz='Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Oracle but often work in SQL Server, I would write query something like this

```
Select Cus from order group by Cus having count(*) = sum(case when Paid = ‘Y’ then 1 else 0);
```

Basically you retrieve customers where total order count equals to sum or paid orders.

Again, apologize for not giving proper Oracle syntax but hopefully that will point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle, you can also do `select customer from your_table where paid='Y' minus select customer from your_table where paid='N'`, although I don't know if this is faster and, of course, you don't get the other fields in this case.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    orders oo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    orders io
            WHERE   oo.cus# = io.cus#
            AND     io.paid = 'N'
        )
;
```

Comment: subquery is not required and recommended here..Please make sure to use SubQs only when necessary..!!

Comment: It works with "Select * from" that is why it is necessary. "EXISTS" in not always required but usually recommended.

Comment: Any subq approach will add to processing time, think of a condition where table contain millions of rows. OP has not mention if he require all the columns with different values of order#. Anyhow that's being the case, can be achieved by using PLAP>